# How do i get values of the checked check boxes and perform an action on each of them in codeigniter?

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

```
<input type="checkbox" value="<? echo $user->roll_no ?>" name ="user[]" /></td>
```

What does the array 'user' store and how do i perform action on each of the element of the array??
What should be the code in model, view and controller for this??

Answer (score 0):

I would use a simple php foreach statement. The array stores the value you're echoing in the html above. Only the checked checkboxes are sent during the form submit.

```
<?php
    foreach($_REQUEST["user"] as $roll_no){
        //perform action here $roll_no is the variable you need
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In controller

```
<?php
function some_function()
{
  $user = $this->input->post('user');
   if(! empty($user))
   {
     foreach($user as $roll_no)
     {
      //ur user roll no value  $roll_no
     } 
   }
 }
```